Where are the "built-in" MSBuild property functions (like [MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault()) defined?
I've been looking for the code for the built-in MSBuild property functions (for example, [MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault()), but I haven't been able to find any yet. Is the source publicly available? If so, where? Thanks.

The source code for ValueOrDefault() is available in the dotnet/msbuild repo in GitHub at
https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/9cdb3615adb4115f92b390de2f258fac5f320909/src/Build/Evaluation/IntrinsicFunctions.cs#L368-L383
'Lookup' of the internal function is done in the TryExecuteWellKnownFunction() method of the Expander class.
